# Tag filter in OCI SDK

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to list VCN in OCI java SDK, but I must list all the VCNs containing particular freeform tag keys and values.

From UI I can do that by setting Tag Filter:
[image]

The following code lists all the avaialble VCNs

```java
        final GetVcnResponse getVcnResponse = vcnClient.getWaiters()
                .forVcn(GetVcnRequest.builder().build(),
                        Vcn.LifecycleState.Available)
                .execute();
```

Can you please share the code SDK API to list VNC with Tag filter?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the client-side filter as below.

```
ListVcnsResponse response = vcnClient.listVcns(ListVcnsRequest.builder()
        .compartmentId(COMPARTMENT_ID)
        .build());

List<Vcn> vcns = response.getItems()
        .stream()
        .filter(vcn -> "value1".equals(vcn.getFreeformTags().get("key1")))
        .toList();

System.out.println(vcns);
```